$\det(A^2-B^2) \leq \det(A^2)$ when $B$ is of rank 1
This is an exercise problem given at linear algebra class. As a problem before this I was able to show that $$\det(A + uv^T) = \det A + v^T (adj A )u$$ when $A$ is order $n$ square matrix and $u,v$ are $n$-dimensional vectors.
Now I am to show this: $\det(A^2-B^2) \leq \det(A^2)$ when $A, B$ are order $n$ square matrices and $rank(B)=1$.
Moreover, using this, I am to show that $\det(A + kX) = \det(A)$ when $A$ is skew-symmetric and $X$ is a matrix with 1's at every entry.
If the problem is to show $\det(A-B)\det(A+B) \leq \det(A^2)$, it would be easy using $\det(A + uv^T) = \det A + v^T (adj A )u$. But for $\det(A^2-B^2)$, I don't know how to start.
Thank you in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

Let $B=uv'$, then
$$\det (A^2 - B^2)=\det(A^2 - (uv'v) u') = \det(A^2) - (u' adj(A^2) u ) (v'v)$$
then show the two factors are both non-negative

@Yimin Can you kindly elaborate why $B^2 = uv’vu’$? I think it should be $uv’uv’$. Isn’t $uv’vu’ = BB^T$?

The first equality you cited needs $A$ to be nonsingular?  Check $A = 0$, $u = v = 1$.

@Zhanxiong I think it is still satisfied whether or not $A$ is invertible. I cannot find why $A=0, u=v=1$ is a counterexample. This is called https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

ok, maybe adj(0) is only defined when $n > 1$.

@mathhello my bad, it is $uv'uv'=(v'u) uv'$ since $v'u$ is a scalar, then you need to deal with $(v'u) v'adj(A^2) u$.

is there any other assumption on $A$?

I think there is something wrong with your skew-symmetric problem in the case where $n$ is odd and $\text{rank}(A) = n-1$.  E.g. with $n=3$, the ones matrix is congruent to $\mathbf e_3\mathbf e_3^T$ and congruence preserves skewness,  so e.g. $C^T XC = \mathbf e_3\mathbf e_3^T$ and  $C^T AC =J= \begin{bmatrix}0& -1&0 \
1 &0&0\ 0&0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ we have $k =\det\big(J + k \mathbf e_3 \mathbf e_3^T\big)  \neq \det\big(J \big) =0$

@user8675309 are you talking about the first equality? The first equality holds if $A$ is invertible

@hmeng I am not talking about the tag.  I am talking about the statement $\det(A + kX) = \det(A)$ "when  is skew-symmetric".  I would like to hear back from OP.

@user8675309 Thank you! I missed some parts of this question

As stated, the inequality is false. Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $B$ has rank one, $A^2 = -I$, and $B^2 = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. Now $A^2 - B^2 = \begin{pmatrix}-3 & -2\\-2 & -3\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $3^2 - 2^2 = 5 > 1 = \det A^2$.
This is not even true when $A$ is positive definite. For if $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\2 & -2\end{pmatrix}$, then $$A^2 - B^2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 4\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\-2 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1\\2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$ has determinant $2^2 - 2(-1) = 6 > 4 = \det A^2$.

if $A$ is positive definite, does that hold?
